# How to use the simple deform modifier/ loop cut an irregular shape?

Tags: objects

I'm trying to bend the object shown in the photo around the z-axis of the axis in front of it. I'm following the process shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq2_goboheo&ab_channel=GamemakerGameProgrammingCourse , but I cannot get it to work for my object. [image: shape with axis in front of it]

In the video the guy uses the loop cut function in order to allow a square bar to bend round an axis, but I cant work out how to apply the correct loop cut to my object. I can only get the following loop cuts:
[image]
[image]
Instead I want the loop cut to run down the face of the object.

And when I use the simple deform modifier the shape awkwardly rotates around the axis and becomes thicker.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this issue, or can someone suggest another way to make a curved object. This object needs to sit flush against a sphere.

Comment: if you want your obect to rotate around Z, it needs the right topology, you can cut a vertical grid with the Knife Project tool for example. Also make sure that you've applied the rotation (Ctrl A (Apply) > Rotation. If it doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score -1):

1. This isn't an issue , this happens due to a big ngon in center of your mesh and not a good "origin position"
2. in this kind of situations , i prefer using Edge crease (Shift+E while selecting boundary edges)
3. also i prefer to learn topology before struggling with software polygonal modeling softwares are different from Cad modeling softwares .
4. I guess you are modeling a gamepad and i don't prefer using deform workflow (which is used in cad programs) just go with "polygon modeling" or watch tutorials about it and go on .
   here is the video that i uploaded for you to use for your purpose btw :   [YoutubeLink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqiVMt4x2qY)